# Set different price for each additional quantity

Tags: magento-1.9, price, tierprice, bundle-product

I want to assign a base price i.e $6 and for each additional quantity i want price to increase by $4.
E.g. If i add 2 quanity of the product than price will be :
**$6 (Base) + $4 (Additional qty price) = $10 Total price**
How do i achieve in Magento.

I did some R&D and all they suggest is price tier. But i think it will also change first quantity(Base) price of the product.

Can anyone please suggest the best possible way to achieve this
[image: Here is the prices for different SKU's including base price and Count price]

Comment: You can use sales cart rules under promotion tab. Here you can make rules as per your requirements.

Comment: Appreciate your help. 
But i dont think this is what i am looking for because the count cost for each product is different. See attached image above in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you can add tier prices for the product.

Go to the product page in the Magento admin area and navigate to the 'Price' tab. There you will have an attribute called 'Tier Price' where you can configure the price per ordered quantity.

[image]

**Edit: As per request a solution with shopping cart price rules:**

You can do this by making 2 separate rules.

**Rule number 1:**

Conditions:

[image]

Actions:

[image]

**Rule number 2:**

Conditions:

[image]

Actions:

[image]

Now make sure that rule 2 is executed **before** rule number 1 by giving it a lower priority and you're done :-) Rule number 1 won't be executed because rule number 2 has 'stop further rules processing' enabled.

You can of course change the conditions to match an attribute like partial SKU or attribute_set instead of a category. This is up to you.